# pagespeed_no_transform attribute not taken in account

Tags: nginx, pagespeed

I'm using the Nginx PageSpeed module, and got an issue when it comes to images managed with [jquery.matchHeight.js](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height). I decided to disable optimization on these specific images, to I added the `pagespeed_no_transform` attribute (I also tried `data-pagespeed-no-transform` without success):

```
<img src="https://example.com/image-icon_300.png" alt="Alt title" pagespeed_no_transform />
```

Unfortunately, PageSpeed does not seem to take this attribute in account. Worse, it purely **remove it** and do the optimization. Below is the rendered code:

```
<img src="https://example.com/image-icon_300.png.pagespeed.ce.gkz42_jTc5@2x.png" alt="Alt title" data-pagespeed-url-hash="627608977" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" width="240" height="200">
```

In cas this would be related to my PageSpeed version/configuration, here is my Nginx conf:

```
# Header X-Page-Speed: 1.13.35.2-0
server {
  # Ansible managed
  pagespeed on;
  pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;

  location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
    add_header "" "";
  }
  location ~ "^/pagespeed_static/" { }
  location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who are facing the same issue, it appears it's perfectly working!

PageSpeed to several optimisations on images, mainly:

- Conversion (to PNG, JPEG or WebP)
- Recompression
- Resizing
- Inlining
- Caching

When using the `data-pagespeed-no-transform` attribute, you're telling PageSpeed to not "transform" your image, **but this not mean it won't be cached**, and this is why you still see the `https://example.com/image-icon_300.png.pagespeed.ce.gkz42_jTc5@2x.png` URL.

To know if your image has been transformed, you need to check its URL:

- Caching only: `image-icon_300.png.pagespeed.ce.gkz42_jTc5@2x.png`
- Resizing + Caching: `150x150ximage-icon_300.png.pagespeed.ce.gkz42_jTc5@2x.png`
- Conversion + Resizing + Caching: `ximage-icon_300.png.pagespeed.ic.gkz42_jTc5@2x.webp`
- Inlining: `data:image/jpeg;base64,…`